# tikz: fitting width of node but automatic height

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, fit

I want to create a diagram in tikz using sth like the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}    
%\input{content/renalBrainshake/gfx/flowchart.tikz}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw, fill=blue, font=\sffamily\tiny}, align=center, node distance = 2.1cm]
    %%%%% COHORT NODES
    %% DIABETICS
    \node (n1)  []              {node1\\ line 2};
    \node (n2)  [right of = n1] {node2\\ line 2};
    \node (n3)  [right of = n2] {node3};
    \node (long)[fit   = (n1)(n3),
            above = 1cm of n1.west,
            anchor= south west, inner sep=0] {long};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are 3 problems:

1. I want the three nodes `n1`, `n2`, `n3` all to have the same height, without having to guess the optimal height using `minimum height`
2. I want the long node to fit the width of the three other nodes, but the height of the `long` node should be automatic according to the text in it
3. The text in `long` should be vertically centered, but here it is not

Does anybody have a good solution to any of this?

Answer (score 6):

Use `fit` also for `n3` and `label=center:text` for text in nodes `n3` and `long`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}    
%\input{content/renalBrainshake/gfx/flowchart.tikz}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw, fill=blue, font=\sffamily\tiny}, align=center, node distance = 2.1cm]
    %%%%% COHORT NODES
    %% DIABETICS
    \node (n1)  []              {node1\\ line 2};
    \node (n2)  [right of = n1] {node2\\ line 2};
    \node (n3)  [fit= (n2), inner sep=0pt, right of = n2, label=center:node3] {};
    \node (long)[fit = (n1)(n3),
            above = 1cm of n1.west,
            anchor= south west, inner sep=0, label=center:long] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

In case you want to adjust the height of `long` node, a partial solution could be:

```
\node (long)[fit = (n1.west)(n3.east),
        above = 1cm of n1.west,
        anchor= south west, inner xsep=0, label=center:{long}, 
        minimum height={height("long")}
        ] {};
```

new `fit` options and `inner xsep=0` define its longitudinal dimension and minimum height={height("long")} (from `calc` tikzlibrary) defines the vertical.

Another solution for nodes with taller contents could be to use an auxiliary node which fixes height and a `fit` node which covers it. The aux node can be created with:

```
\node (aux) [above = 1cm of n1.west, anchor=south west, fill=red!30] {long\\long\\long};
```

It's a regular node which is placed where we want it (`above = 1cm of n1.west, anchor=south west`) and with adjusted size to contain its text.

Now we can use its anchors to define the new node as long as previous n1, n2 and n3 and adjusted height to its contents.

```
\node (long)[fit = {(n1.west|-aux.south)(n3.east|-aux.north)},
            above = 1cm of n1.west,
            anchor= south west, 
            opacity = .5, %<--- delete this line in final figure
            inner sep=-.5\pgflinewidth, label=center:{long\\ long\\ long}, 
          ] {};
```

As you can see `fit = {(n1.west|-aux.south)(n3.east|-aux.north)}` and `inner sep=-.5\pgflinewidth` define news node size.

And `opacity=.5` has been include to also see `aux` node. Comment out this line or delete it before producing the final result.

All fitting nodes in following code include `inner sep=-.5\pgflinewidth`. This way, `fit` nodes will have the exact size of referenced ones. With `inner sep=0pt`, fitting nodes include reference anchors inside its borders, which means that the resultant nodes are half line width larger than fitted ones.

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}    
%\input{content/renalBrainshake/gfx/flowchart.tikz}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw, fill=blue!50, font=\sffamily\tiny}, align=center, node distance = 2.1cm]
    %%%%% COHORT NODES
    %% DIABETICS
    \node (n1)  []              {node1\\ line 2};
    \node (n2)  [right of = n1] {node2\\ line 2};
    \node (n3)  [fit= (n2), inner sep=-.5\pgflinewidth, right of = n2, label=center:node3] {};
    \node (aux) [above = 1cm of n1.west, anchor=south west, fill=red!30] {long\\long\\long};

    \node (long)[fit = {(n1.west|-aux.south)(n3.east|-aux.north)},
            above = 1cm of n1.west,
            anchor= south west, 
            opacity = .5,
            inner sep=-.5\pgflinewidth, label=center:{long\\ long\\ long}, 
          ] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! that solves problems 1. and 3., but not 2. the `long` node is still higher than it has to be.

Comment: @Jonas I've updated the answer with a possible solution.

Comment: @Jonas If this answer helped you and solved your question, please consider up-voting and accepting it. If it didn't solve your problem satisfactorily, you might want to leave another comment and explain why.

Comment: Do you know the reason for -1?